# react gives me a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm working on some react projects and i've tried to orginize my code by moving some components to another files then import them but when i do that it just give me a blank page , when i write (import Header from "./Header") it starts to give blank page while it was working when i was putting all of the code in index.js only .
this is my main index code:

```
import Header from "./Header"
import Footer from "./Footer"
import Maincontent from "./Main"

function Page(){
    return(
        <div>
        <Header />
        <Maincontent/>
        <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

and this is my header code

```
export default function Header(){
    return(
    <header>
        <nav className="nav">
            <img src="./react-logo.png" className="img" />
            <ul className="nav-items">
                <li> Pricing </li>
                <li> About </li>
                <li> Contact </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you export `Header`, like this `export default Header`, at the end of your component file?

Comment: I think you already have a answer, but for future when ever you want to import a component you have to export it first

Comment: i did export it but it gives me also an error at js console is : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at <anonymous>:3:15 at i (babel.min.js:24:29679) at r (babel.min.js:24:30188) at e.src.n.<computed>.l.content (babel.min.js:24:30503) at n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24:29946)

Comment: try exporting at the bottom of the page , like function Header(){ }, and on the end of the page, export default Header

Answer (score 1):

You need to export `Header`. Try putting `export default Header` at the bottom of your `Header` component file.

Comment: i did export it i just forgot to put it in the question but it gives  me an error in the console when i run it its :    Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at <anonymous>:3:15 at i (babel.min.js:24:29679) at r (babel.min.js:24:30188) at e.src.n.<computed>.l.content (babel.min.js:24:30503) at n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24:29946) , so ithink the problem is in babel but i don't really know how to fix it iam gonna try to delete react fully from my pc the re install it i hope it work perfectly + i can use your help brother .